# Can we extend the Grownall inequality to infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

For integral form of the Grownall inequality in [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grönwall%27s_inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality):

> Assume that $\beta$ and $u$ are continuous. If $\beta$ is non-negative and $u$ satisfies the integral inequality:
> $$
> u(t)\le \alpha(t)+\int_a^t\beta(s)u(s)ds
> $$
> Moreover, assume that $\alpha(t)$ is non-decreasing.
> Then
> $$
> u(t)\le \alpha(t)\exp(\int_a^t \beta(s)ds)
> $$

My question is that if we have
$$
u(t)\le C+\int_t^{\infty} \beta(s)u(s)ds
$$

Can we still have the above Grownall inequality? That is
$$
u(t)\le C\exp(\int_t^\infty \beta(s)ds)
$$

Comment: Does the standart proof fail at some point? At first glance, the proof from the wikipedia seems to be working for the differrential version of  Gronwall on $[t,\infty)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standart proof does work in the described situation.  Define
$$
v(t) = \exp\left(-\int_t^{\infty}\beta(s)\,ds\right)\cdot \int_t^{\infty}\beta(s)u(s)\,ds.
$$
Notice that if $\beta\notin L^1([t, \infty))$ the the claim is trivial, otherwise $g$ is well-defined. We have then
$$
v'(s) = \exp\left(-\int_t^{\infty}\beta(s)\,ds\right)\left[\beta(t)\int_t^{\infty}\beta(s)u(s)\,ds - \beta(t)u(t)\right]
\\
=\exp\left(-\int_t^{\infty}\beta(s)\,ds\right)\beta(t)\left[\int_t^{\infty}\beta(s)u(s)\,ds - u(t)\right]
\\
\ge -C\exp\left(-\int_t^{\infty}\beta(s)\,ds\right)\beta(t).
$$
It is clear that $v(\infty) = \lim_{t\to\infty}v(t) = 0$ hence
$$
-v(t) = v(\infty) - v(t) = \int_t^{\infty}v'(s)\, ds\ge -C\int_t^{\infty}\exp\left(-\int_s^{\infty}\beta(r)\,dr\right)\beta(s)\, ds,
\\
v(t)\le C\int_t^{\infty}\exp\left(-\int_s^{\infty}\beta(r)\,dr\right)\beta(s)\, ds.
$$
Recalling the definition of $v$, we get
$$
\int_t^{\infty}\beta(s)u(s)\,ds = v(t)\cdot \exp\left(\int_t^{\infty}\beta(s)\,ds\right)
\\
\le C\int_t^{\infty}\exp\left(-\int_s^{\infty}\beta(r)\,dr + \int_t^{\infty}\beta(x)\,dx\right)\beta(s)\, ds
\\
=C\int_t^{\infty}\exp\left( \int_t^{s}\beta(r)\,dr\right)\beta(s)\, ds = 
C\int_t^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\exp\left( \int_t^{s}\beta(r)\,dr\right)\, ds
\\
=C\exp\left(\int_t^s\beta(r)\,dr\right)\bigg|_{s = t}^{s = \infty} = C\exp\left(\int_t^{\infty}\beta(r)\,dr\right) - C.
$$
To conclude the proof substitute this into the initial inequality:
$$
u(t) \le C + \int_t^{\infty}\beta(s)u(s)\,ds \le C\exp\left(\int_t^{\infty}\beta(r)\,dr\right).
$$